# Algorithm to efficiently determine the [n][n] element in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, big-o

This is a question regarding a piece of coursework so would rather you didn't fully answer the question but rather give tips to improve the run time complexity of my current algorithm.

I have been given the following information:

A function g(n) is given by g(n) = f(n,n) where f may be defined recursively by

[image]

I have implemented this algorithm recursively with the following code:

```
public static double f(int i, int j) 
{

    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (i ==0 || j == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return ((f(i-1, j)) + (f(i-1, j-1)) + (f(i, j-1)))/3;
}
```

This algorithm gives the results I am looking for, but it is extremely inefficient and I am now tasked to improve the run time complexity.

I wrote an algorithm to create an n*n matrix and it then computes every element up to the [n][n] element in which it then returns the [n][n] element, for example f(1,1) would return 0.6 recurring. The [n][n] element is 0.6 recurring because it is the result of (1+0+1)/3.

I have also created a spreadsheet of the result from f(0,0) to f(7,7) which can be seen below:

[image: Results]

Now although this is much faster than my recursive algorithm, it has a huge overhead of creating a n*n matrix.

Any suggestions to how I can improve this algorithm will be greatly appreciated!

I can now see that is it possible to make the algorithm O(n) complexity, but is it possible to work out the result without creating a [n][n] 2D array?

I have created a solution in Java that runs in O(n) time and O(n) space and will post the solution after I have handed in my coursework to stop any plagiarism.

Comment: Convert the for loop from O(n*n) to O(n).

Comment: "Now although this is much faster than my recursive algorithm I know it can become much more efficient!" 
because .... ?
I don't say you are wrong, I just say that when you are so sure about something, you could explain what make you so sure

Comment: You could "unroll" the recursion and apply arithmetic simplifications where possible.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to create a [n][n] array because in your calculations you only need [x-1] and [y-1] values, so you can have just a linear array of [n] for storing the values from the previous iteration.

Comment: Although some of the posts until now contain some helpful, general information for tasks like this (particularly the reference to the OEIS), **none** of them really helps to answer the question: The denominator part is rather trivial. In contrast to that, the numerator resisted all of my analysis attempts until now (that, by the way, went far beyond trying to paste the sequence to OEIS...). I'm curious whether someone comes up with a closed-form solution for this one...

Comment: @Marco13 see my combinatorical answer, it's closed-form.

Comment: @Marco13 ditto mine.

Comment: @גלעדברקן i don't see how your answer is closed form, you do not give a formula for the result.

Comment: @will So write one! I described the method clearly enough.

Comment: Using a `NxN` matrix, you can't achieve `O(N)` !

Comment: This question is incomplete (actually, there is no question in the text !). Do you need to compute all values of `f` in `[0 N]x[0 N]` or a few of them or just one ?

Answer (score 6):

This is another one of those questions where it's better to examine it, before diving in and writing code.

The first thing i'd say you should do is look at a grid of the numbers, and to not represent them as decimals, but fractions instead.

The first thing that should be obvious is that the total number of [image] you have is just a measure of the distance from the origin, [image].

If you look at a grid in this way, you can get all of the denominators:

[image]

Note that the first row and column are not all `1`s - they've been chosen to follow the pattern, and the general formula which works for all of the other squares.

The numerators are a little bit more tricky, but still doable. As with most problems like this, the answer is related to combinations, factorials, and then some more complicated things. Typical entries here include [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), [Stirling's numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number), [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), and you will nearly always see [Hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) used.

Unless you do a *lot* of maths, it's unlikely you're familiar with all of these, and there is a hell of a lot of literature. So I have an easier way to find out the relations you need, which nearly always works. It goes like this:

1. Write a naive, inefficient algorithm to get the sequence you want.
2. Copy a reasonably large amount of the numbers into google.
3. Hope that a result from the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) pops up.

   3.b. If one doesn't, then look at some differences in your sequence, or some other sequence related to your data.
4. Use the information you find to implement said sequence.

So, following this logic, here are the numerators:

[image]

Now, unfortunately, googling those yielded nothing. However, there are a few things you can notice about them, the main being that the first row/column are just powers of 3, and that the second row/column are one less than powers of three. This kind boundary is exactly the same as Pascal's triangle, and a lot of related sequences.

Here is the matrix of differences between the numerators and denominators:

[image]

Where we've decided that the f(0,0) element shall just follow the same pattern. These numbers already look much simpler. Also note though - rather interestingly, that these numbers follow the same rules as the initial numbers - except the that the first number is one (and they are offset by a column and a row). `T(i,j) = T(i-1,j) + T(i,j-1) + 3*T(i-1,j-1)`:

```
                     1 
                  1     1
               1     5     1
            1     9     9     1
         1     13    33    13    1
      1     17    73    73    17    1
   1     21    129   245   192   21    1
1     25    201   593   593   201   25    1
```

This looks more like the sequences you see a lot in combinatorics.

[If you google numbers from this matrix, you do get a hit.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=1+25+289+2073+10497&oq=1+25+289+2073+10497&aqs=chrome..69i57.1363j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=1+25+289+2073+10497+40665)

And then if you cut off the link to the raw data, you get sequence [A081578](http://oeis.org/A081578), which is described as a "Pascal-(1,3,1) array", which exactly makes sense - if you rotate the matrix, so that the `0,0` element is at the top, and the elements form a triangle, then you take `1*` the left element, `3*` the above element, and `1*` the right element.

The question now is implementing the formulae used to generate the numbers.

Unfortunately, this is often easier said than done. For example, the formula given on the page:

> T(n,k)=sum{j=0..n, C(k,j-k)*C(n+k-j,k)*3^(j-k)}

is wrong, and it takes a fair bit of reading [the paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL9/Barry/barry91.pdf) (linked on the page) to work out the correct formula. The sections you want are proposition 26, corollary 28. The sequence is mentioned in Table 2 after proposition 13. Note that `r=4`

The correct formula is given in proposition 26, but there is also a typo there :/. The `k=0` in the sum should be a `j=0`:

[image]

Where `T` is the triangular matrix containing the coefficients.

The OEIS page does give a couple of implementations to calculate the numbers, but neither of them are in java, and neither of them can be easily transcribed to java:

There is a mathematica example:

```js
Table[ Hypergeometric2F1[-k, k-n, 1, 4], {n, 0, 10}, {k, 0, n}] // Flatten
```

which, as always, is ridiculously succinct. And there is also a Haskell version, which is equally terse:

```hs
a081578 n k = a081578_tabl !! n !! k
a081578_row n = a081578_tabl !! n
a081578_tabl = map fst $ iterate
   (\(us, vs) -> (vs, zipWith (+) (map (* 3) ([0] ++ us ++ [0])) $
                      zipWith (+) ([0] ++ vs) (vs ++ [0]))) ([1], [1, 1])
```

I know you're doing this in java, but i could not be bothered to transcribe my answer to java (sorry). Here's a python implementation:

```py
from __future__ import division
import math

#
# Helper functions
#

def cache(function):
  cachedResults = {}
  def wrapper(*args):
    if args in cachedResults:
      return cachedResults[args]
    else:
      result = function(*args)
      cachedResults[args] = result
      return result
  return wrapper


@cache
def fact(n):
 return math.factorial(n)

@cache
def binomial(n,k):
  if n < k: return 0
  return fact(n) / ( fact(k) * fact(n-k) )





def numerator(i,j):
  """
  Naive way to calculate numerator
  """
  if i == j == 0:
    return 0
  elif i == 0 or j == 0:
    return 3**(max(i,j)-1)
  else:
    return numerator(i-1,j) + numerator(i,j-1) + 3*numerator(i-1,j-1)

def denominator(i,j):
  return 3**(i+j-1)



def A081578(n,k):
  """
  http://oeis.org/A081578
  """
  total = 0
  for j in range(n-k+1):
    total += binomial(k, j) * binomial(n-k, j) * 4**(j)
  return int(total)

def diff(i,j):
  """
  Difference between the numerator, and the denominator. 
  Answer will then be 1-diff/denom.
  """
  if i == j == 0:
    return 1/3
  elif i==0 or j==0:
    return 0
  else:
    return A081578(j+i-2,i-1)

def answer(i,j):
  return 1 - diff(i,j) / denominator(i,j)




# And a little bit at the end to demonstrate it works.
N, M = 10,10

for i in range(N):
  row = "%10.5f"*M % tuple([numerator(i,j)/denominator(i,j) for j in range(M)])
  print row

print ""
for i in range(N):
  row = "%10.5f"*M % tuple([answer(i,j) for j in range(M)])
  print row
```

So, for a closed form:

[image]

Where the [image] are just binomial coefficients.

Here's the result:

[image]

One final addition, if you are looking to do this for large numbers, then you're going to need to compute the binomial coefficients a different way, as you'll overflow the integers. Your answers are lal floating point though, and since you're apparently interested in large `f(n) = T(n,n)` then I guess you could use Stirling's approximation or something.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your closed formula - please correct me if I'm wrong: `F(2,2) = 1 - (2 choose 0 * 0 choose 0 * 4^2 + 2 choose 1 * 0 choose 1 * 4^2) / 3^3 = 0.4074` This result seems different than the OP's and mine. Can you help me understand what's going on?

Comment: @גלעדברקן whoops, i forgot to transform the matrix indices. Just a sec.

Comment: Cool. By the way, I finally added a formula and proof of concept in JavaScript to my answer, although from the material you found it looks like my math can be further reduced. In any case, I'm proud to have come up with it on my own.

Comment: Can you make this formula work on a computer, practically, for `n = 1000000` ? I haven't had much success.

Comment: You'd need to change the way the factorials are computed in the `nCr`s - those are the issues you'll always have. If an approximation is okay, then there are plenty of approximations for `n!`. Getting the correct integer representation is going to be much more difficult.

Comment: If you want the `exact` answer, you have to do it using integer arithmetic. But then the denominator is going to be so large that you have to use variable precision maths, and so you're going to lose a *huge* amount of performance.

Comment: The problem I've been having using Haskell BigFloat and inherent BigInteger is that even just **one** division, somewhere in the middle of the sum for `n = 1000000`, takes so long to be practical.

Comment: Well Yah, the factorials with numbers that big are *huge*.

Comment: I guess my point is that the math route might no be the optimal way to answer the op's question after all. He mentioned in a comment that he needs to show `f(1000000)`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן but the problem i see with going the recursive route is that there will be so many divisions by three - which the binary math can't resolve exactly - that it will jsut be random noise by that point. Which gives me an idea - do it in base 3, then the divide by threes become bit shifts, and additions will be pretty simple too, as well as the whole thing being represented exactly. I'm gonna try and implement it in base three, just using bit shifts and simple addition.

Comment: the base 3 is a very interesting idea!

Comment: I have something in the works, but it's slow - am searching for a pattern of some kind.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Having looked at it a bit further, it looks like the ternary method boils down to almost your method exactly (i removed the carries to represent the decimal part, and it starts looking a lot more similar).

Comment: I wonder if there actually is a practical method for such large `n`. (btw, two slight optimizations are (1) start in the middle and end the loop before it adds elements insignificant for some arbitrary precision, and (2) use the closed form for summing half way to `n` and add/subtract to that.)

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters here are some things to keep in mind:

This condition can only occur once, yet you test it every time through every loop.

```
if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
    matrix[x][y] = 0;
}
```

You should instead: `matrix[0][0] = 0;` right before you enter your first loop and set x to 1. Since you know x will never be 0 you can remove the first part of your second condition `x == 0` :

```
for(int x = 1; x <= i; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <= j; y++)
            {             
                if (y == 0) {
                    matrix[x][y] = 1;
                }
                else
                matrix[x][y] = (matrix[x-1][y] + matrix[x-1][y-1] + matrix[x][y-1])/3;
            }
        }
```

No point in declaring row and column since you only use it once. `double[][] matrix = new double[i+1][j+1];`

Answer (score 1):

To describe time complexity we usually use a big O notation. It is important to remember that it only describes the growth given the input. O(n) is linear time complexity, but it doesn't say how quickly (or slowly) the time grows when we increase input. For example:

```
n=3 -> 30 seconds
n=4 -> 40 seconds
n=5 -> 50 seconds
```

This is O(n), we can clearly see that every increase of n increases the time by 10 seconds.

```
n=3 -> 60 seconds
n=4 -> 80 seconds
n=5 -> 100 seconds
```

This is also O(n), even though for every n we need twice that much time, and the raise is 20 seconds for every increase of n, the time complexity grows linearly.

So if you have O(n*n) time complexity and you will half the number of operations you perform, you will get O(0.5*n*n) which is equal to O(n*n) - i.e. your time complexity won't change.

This is theory, in practice the number of operations sometimes makes a difference. Because you have a grid n by n, you need to fill n*n cells, so the best time complexity you can achieve is O(n*n), but there are a few optimizations you can do:

- Cells on the edges of the grid could be filled in separate loops. Currently in majority of the cases you have two unnecessary conditions for i and j equal to 0.
- You grid has a line of symmetry, you could utilize it to calculate only half of it and then copy the results onto the other half. For every i and j `grid[i][j] = grid[j][i]`

On final note, the clarity and readability of the code is much more important than performance - if you can read and understand the code, you can change it, but if the code is so ugly that you cannot understand it, you cannot optimize it. That's why I would do only first optimization (it also increases readability), but wouldn't do the second one - it would make the code much more difficult to understand.

As a rule of thumb, don't optimize the code, unless the performance is really causing problems. As William Wulf said:

> More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason - including blind stupidity.

**EDIT:**

I think it may be possible to implement this function with O(1) complexity. Although it gives no benefits when you need to fill entire grid, with O(1) time complexity you can instantly get any value without having a grid at all.

[image: Grid]

A few observations:

- denominator is equal to `3 ^ (i + j - 1)`
- if i = 2 or j = 2, numerator is one less than denominator

**EDIT 2:**

The numerator can be expressed with the following function:

```
public static int n(int i, int j) {
    if (i == 1 || j == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 3 * n(i - 1, j - 1) + n(i - 1, j) + n(i, j - 1);
    }
}
```

Very similar to original problem, but no division and all numbers are integers.

Comment: Your last edit is wrong, you can reduce the number of additions, but that would increase the number multiplications. So you need to do at least `Ω(n)` arithmetical operations. Precomputing the factor for every possible `n` is impossible.

Comment: The bit you have at the end is the correct way to solve problems like this i think. Look at the problem, and spot the pattern.

Comment: Also, if you have to fill the entire grid, it will actually be more efficient to do it the naive way, as the individual computations will be simpler. But the question is specifically abotu the diagonal terms.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm has a minimum complexity of `Ω(n)` because you just need to multiply the values in the first column and row of the matrix with some factors and then add them up. The factors stem from unwinding the recursion `n` times.

However you therefore need to do the unwinding of the recursion. That itself has a complexity of `O(n^2)`. But by balancing unwinding and evaluation of recursion, you should be able to reduce complexity to `O(n^x)` where `1 <= x <= 2`. This is some kind of similiar to algorithms for matrix-matrix multiplication, where the naive case has a complexity of `O(n^3)` but Strassens's algorithm is for example `O(n^2.807)`.

Another point is the fact that the original formula uses a factor of `1/3`. Since this is not accurately representable by fixed point numbers or ieee 754 floating points, the error increases when evaluating the recursion successively. Therefore unwinding the recursion could give you higher accuracy as a nice side effect.

For example when you unwind the recursion `sqr(n)` times then you have complexity `O((sqr(n))^2+(n/sqr(n))^2)`. The first part is for unwinding and the second part is for evaluating a new matrix of size `n/sqr(n)`. That new complexity actually can be simplified to **`O(n)`**.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about how to output all values of the function for `0<=i<N`, `0<=j<N`, here is a solution in time `O(N²)` and space `O(N)`. The time behavior is optimal.

```
Use a temporary array T of N numbers and set it to all ones, except for the first element.

Then row by row,

    use a temporary element TT and set it to 1,
    then column by column, assign simultaneously T[I-1], TT = TT, (TT + T[I-1] + T[I])/3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to will's (first) answer, I had this idea:

Consider that any positive solution comes only from the `1`'s along the `x` and `y` axes. Each of the recursive calls to `f` divides each component of the solution by 3, which means we can sum, combinatorially, how many ways each `1` features as a component of the solution, and consider it's "distance" (measured as how many calls of `f` it is from the target) as a negative power of 3.

JavaScript code:

```
function f(n){

  var result = 0;

  for (var d=n; d<2*n; d++){

    var temp = 0;

    for (var NE=0; NE<2*n-d; NE++){

      temp += choose(n,NE);
    }

    result += choose(d - 1,d - n) * temp / Math.pow(3,d);
  }

  return 2 * result;
 }

function choose(n,k){
  if (k == 0 || n == k){
    return 1;
  }
  var product = n;
  for (var i=2; i<=k; i++){
    product *= (n + 1 - i) / i
  }
  return product;
}
```

Output:

```
for (var i=1; i<8; i++){
  console.log("F(" + i + "," + i + ") = " + f(i));
}

F(1,1) = 0.6666666666666666
F(2,2) = 0.8148148148148148
F(3,3) = 0.8641975308641975
F(4,4) = 0.8879743941472337
F(5,5) = 0.9024030889600163
F(6,6) = 0.9123609205913732
F(7,7) = 0.9197747256986194
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? The 0 0 delannoy number is 1, where as for the sequence here it is 0. The delannoy numbers also do not have factors of three as divisors. It is undoubtedly related to the answer though, as it's related to the catalan numbers, and they show up all over the place in questions like this.

Comment: @will As you pointed out, the Delannoy recurrence relation is only similar but not the same as my idea. Whereas a Delannoy Number counts the paths both with and without diagonals, my method has to separate paths according to their length (which is then applied as a distinct negative power of 3). Check out my logic - as my examples show, I believe it is sound.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you added some new stuff since i read it. I've found another solution using a derivative of Pascal's triangle - which is always involved!

Comment: The Delannoy numbers are also mentioned in the paper I'm reading at the moment, there's a bunch of stuff i'm not 100% on in here, and some stuff on generalised pascal triangles and the like.

Comment: Could someone give some more information on this answer? I'm still trying to write an algorithm for large numbers, up to f(1000000,1000000) and how I'm currently doing it I am limited to the memory I have available.

Comment: @Thody Thody, which part could I make more clear to you? The method involves combinatoric calculations of all the possible paths from relevant `1`s to the target, applying the length of the paths as negative powers of 3.

Comment: @will Actually (as you can see in the revisions), I only changed the sentence about Delannoy numbers. The method I described stayed the same.

Comment: @גלעדברקן coudl you provide a closed form for your solution? Then we can compare.

Comment: @Thody Thody, I added further explanation and code, although from the material will found, it looks like my math could be further reduced and made more efficient.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I've had a look at your code, you have overcomplicated things a lot, and just by removing the variables `N`, `E` and `NE` (i.e. put everything in terms of `n` and the loop counters) it becomes a lot simpler. [here](http://js.do/code/53906)'s my current refactoring.

Comment: @will I don't see how I can put everything in terms of `n` since `d` and `NE` need to vary, although `E` and `N` could be expressed through the other variables. But that's just semantics, it would be nice if the math could be simplified to O(n).

Comment: @גלעדברקן read the code in my link. I got there just by substituting in each of your `E=N-NE` bits and cancelling out everything i could. For example, you can change your first loop to go from 0 to n and then just replace every `d` with `d+n`.

Comment: You can't simplify the math to O(n), as it contains sums. You can optimize out sections of it, but that doesn't change the O(X) nature or the solution.

Comment: @will If the formula you present at the end of your answer offers the same solutions as mine for `F(n,n)`, well there's a simpler version of the same mathematical transformations of `n`. I find it interesting that that formula only applies one exponent to 3.

Comment: I was more surprised by the factor of 4**j in there!

Comment: I have a solution written in Java that runs in O(n) time complexity as well as O(n) space complexity, I'll post the solution after the coursework has been submitted. Although in reality this solution is O(n*n) but is able to give the same results in O(n) due to precision.

Comment: @thody great, does it use the formula from will's research?

Comment: No, I just used a pattern I found from looking at a table of results. It runs in  O(n^2) time complexity without taking advantage of the double precision error, O(n) with it, and order (n) space complexity in both cases. It gets the result of g(1000000) with the O(n^2) algorithm in 1 hour 20 minutes if anyone wants to compare their timing results to this.

Comment: @Thody How do you take advantage of a double precision error?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I wouldn't really say it's an error actually, but as the numbers converge towards 1 and the type double reaches its maximum precision then the result of the calculations get rounded to one. If you look at the table of results you can see that each column only needs the previous column to work out its values, which is the O(n) space complexity, and if you keep track of the number of ones in the previous column, then the column after will have just as many, if not more, so you do not need to work out those cells, you just assume that it is one. This gives O(n) run time complexity.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Although, this does not give the exact result, but does give the computational result. If you worked it out by hand you would get a more accurate answer assuming you could work out the result to a very large number of decimal places. I tried using BigDecimal objects instead of type double which have an infinite precision if I remember correctly. This in theory would give the correct result but takes so long to compute values with really high precision I couldn't manage to run it for a really high value of n.

Comment: @Thody That's what I was wondering. How precise are you expected to be for the assignment? The Haskell program I wrote with the formula listed by will already converged to 1 around f(325) using float number types.

Comment: @Thody by the way, if you are relying on the previous column to work out each column's values, that is `O(n^2)` complexity, not `O(n)`, since you have `n*(n+1)/2` operations.